# Redirect localhost:5000/some_path to localhost:5000

Tags: python, api, flask

I have a dockenizer flask api app that runs in `localhost:5000`. The api runs with no problem. But when I tried to use it by another app, which I cannot change, it uses `localhost:5000/some_path`.

I'd like to redirect from `localhost:5000/some_path` to `localhost:5000`.

I have read that I can use a prefix in my flask api app, but I'd prefer another approach. I don't want to mess with the code.

Is there a redirect/middleware or another way to redirect this traffic?

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: "3.1"

services:
  my-db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./0_schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_schema.sql
      - ./1_data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1_data.sql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: my-db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  my-api:
    build: ../my-awesome-api/
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a web server to serve your application you could manage it with it, for example with nginx you could do:

```
location = /some_path {
  return 301 /;
}
```

Or you can use a middleware:

```
class PrefixMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app, prefix=""):
        self.app = app
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):

        if environ["PATH_INFO"].startswith(self.prefix):
            environ["PATH_INFO"] = environ["PATH_INFO"][len(self.prefix) :]
            environ["SCRIPT_NAME"] = self.prefix
            return self.app(environ, start_response)
        else:
            #handle not found
```

Then register your middleware by adding the prefix to "ignore"

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = PrefixMiddleware(biosfera_fe.wsgi_app, prefix="/some_path")
```

Comment: Thanks Matteo, I will give a try to nginx